# Linking a Category Image

Tags: categories

Is it possible to link a category image in Expression Engine 2+? I have logos as my category images and I'd like to link them to external sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely - you could create a custom category field for the URL and then use it in your template conditionally if it has a value.

Comment: Just wish with custom category fields you could have access to all the same amazing custom channel fields. Ah well!